# Google Chrome - add to homescreen - force refresh

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

I have a website with "add to homescreen" enabled - i.e. I have got a `manifest.json` file with `"display": "standalone"`.

The problem I'm having is when I open the website via the homescreen shortcut, it will resume from when I last accessed it. I have to pull to refresh to make it fetch the latest content.

My question is, is it possible to make it do a refresh every time it is accessed?

Comment: That is the way a PWA works by design/default. When opened it pulls from browser cache and loads updated code in the background. Next time it is opened it will load that update. Are you talking about data retrieved via HTTP calls, or changes to the structure of your site?

Comment: @Mathias it's just a regular website built in PHP, i.e - to get the latest content you need to refresh the page.

Comment: Does content mean the application that you changed or data from a service your application calls? And does it update the second time you open it as I described?

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to take specific action inside of your web app whenever it moves from the "background" to the "foreground" again, you could listen for the appropriate events using the [Page Lifecycle API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/page-lifecycle-api).

The most straightforward way of doing this would probably be to listen for `visibilitychange` events, and programmatically refresh your data source when you detect that the current `visibilityState` has transitioned to `'visible'`.

This could look like:

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', () => {
  if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
    // Your refresh logic goes here.
  }
});
```

Comment: This also works for iPhone, after the recent iOS update which caches the state of a home screen web app. This listener is called every time the app is opened.